# Lock some cells from editing in python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm using [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) to work with Microsoft Excel files (.xlsx/.xlsm), however I am struggling to lock cells (ie. prevent editing). My current code is this:

```
lock = Protection(locked=True,
                    hidden=False)
ws['A1'].protection = lock  # ws is my worksheet
```

However, I am still able to edit cell `A1`. How can I fix it?

**Edit:**

This [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/a5tYaNc2WSk) (to a `openpyxl` email chain) recommends locking the entire sheet and then to unlock all of the cells but for `A1`. However, this does not look like a reliable solution as I'll be dumping large amounts of data.

Answer (score 17):

Lock the entire sheet:

```
    ws.protection.sheet = True
```

Then unlock the cells that can be edited

```
     cell.protection = Protection(locked=False)
```

Comment: Great this works. But this also locks users from changing column widths and row heights. Any advice? If you have an answer to that, could you please respond to my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74807245/how-to-unlock-column-widths-and-row-heights-in-openpyxl

Answer (score 5):

You also need to set protection for the whole worksheet. The specification says this about protection for individual cells:

> A boolean value indicating if the cell is locked. When cells are
>   marked as "locked" and the sheet is protected, then the options
>   specified in the Sheet Part's sheetProtection element (§18.3.1.85) are
>   prohibited for these cells.