# How to unlock column widths and row heights in openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

I have an excel file.

I needed to lock the first column.

To achieve this in `openpyxl`, I locked the entire sheet using `ws.protection.sheet = True` and unlocked the columns mentioned above.

However, locking the entire sheet also prevents users from resizing the columns or row widths and heights.

It is not possible to do `Protection(locked=False)` because it only works on rows and columns with `indices >= 1`.

The code to lock the columns is written below:

```
ws.protection.sheet = True

for i in range(1, max_row + 1):
    ws.cell(row=i, column=1).protection = Protection(locked=True)
```

Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow resizing of the columns and rows

After

```
ws.protection.sheet = True
```

The following are set to True so need to change to False

```
ws.protection.formatColumns = False
ws.protection.formatRows = False
```